# Move already drawn image python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to visually move an already drawn image?
Without having to redraw it each time it's moved?
So, show the square intact and moving in some direction.

```
from turtle import * 
def drawing():
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
drawing()
done()
```

Comment: you can't move it with Turtle. You have to redraw it. `Turtle` uses `Tkinter` which use `Canvas` which has function `move` to move object on canvas  but it can be difficult to get access to canvas and get access to objects on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

`turtle` doesn't have special function to move all elements.

But `turtle` uses `tkinter` which uses `Canvas` object to display elements.
`Canvas` has function to get all displayed elements and move them.

`turtle` gives access to canvas (`get_canvas()`) but later you have to know `tkinter` to do something with canvas and elements.

This example draw element and then it moves by `(300, 50)`.
You can also click turtle and drag it to move all elements.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

# --- move all elements ---

def move(offset_x, offset_y):

    canvas = turtle.getcanvas() # `turtle`, not `t`
    for element_id in canvas.find_all():
        canvas.move(element_id, offset_x, offset_y)

# --- move all on draging turtle ---

old_x = 0
old_y = 0

# get mouse current position
def on_click(x, y):
    global old_x, old_y

    old_x = x
    old_y = y

# move elements
def on_drag(x, y):
    global old_x, old_y

    move(x-old_x, old_y-y)

    old_x = x
    old_y = y

t.onclick(on_click)
t.ondrag(on_drag)

# --- example ---

# draw something 

for a in range(8):
    for _ in range(8):
        t.left(45)
        t.fd(20)
    t.right(45)
    t.up()
    t.fd(60)
    t.down()

# move

move(300, 50)

# ---

turtle.done() # `turtle`, not `t`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move it with Turtle without dropping down to the `tkinter` level if all you need to move is a collection of simple, filled polygons (though you can emulate an unfilled polygon by using a white fill color with non-white pen color.)  You can create a custom turtle with your shape and move that turtle around the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed("fastest")
turtle.penup()

shape = Shape("compound")

for octogon in range(8):
    turtle.begin_poly()
    for _ in range(8):
        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.fd(20)
    turtle.end_poly()
    shape.addcomponent(turtle.get_poly(), "blue", "red")

    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.fd(60)

screen.register_shape("octogons", shape)

octopus = Turtle(shape="octogons")
octopus.penup()
octopus.speed("slowest")

octopus.goto(300, 200)
octopus.goto(-200, 200)

screen.exitonclick()
```