# I need a way to group objects together, i need to make a plane

Tags: python, python-turtle

I need a way to group these together
could someone help me
im making a plane, the whole game could be posted if needed

```
# The Plane Body
plane = turtle.Turtle()
plane.speed(0)
plane.shape("square")
plane.color("black")
plane.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=4)
plane.penup()
plane.goto(-400, 0)
# The Plane Front
planeF = turtle.Turtle()
planeF.speed(0)
planeF.shape("triangle")
planeF.color("dark gray")
planeF.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=4)
planeF.penup()
planeF.goto(-350, 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by grouping together?  You could define a function that creates a plane component, taking speed, shape, color etc.  Do you know how to do that?  Would that resolve your question?

Comment: grouping by pairs between plane and planeF? what kind of output do you expect?

Comment: I second @gerrit's suggestion. You should learn about functions so that you can organize your code into logical units.

Comment: its a game where you try to dodge missiles being launched a you, you only go up and down

Comment: i just want to know how to control all the plan parts at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move already drawn image python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622576/move-already-drawn-image-python-turtle)

Comment: no sorry, but i just fiqured it out